# Shopify: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in theme.js

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, token, shopify

Weird one this morning. Was working on some updates to a Shopify store (https://veilcosmetics.com/) and all of a sudden, the AJAX cart stopped functioning. Went into Console. Not a lot of errors, but there was one in the theme.js file which was a 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in theme.js' type of issue. It's odd because I didn't tweak this file's code at all. So why would it be issuing an error? Here's the problematic code which starts at '@function'.

```
/*================ SASS HELPERS ================*/
/*============================================================================
  Convert pixels to ems
  eg. for a relational value of 12px write em(12) when the parent is 16px
  if the parent is another value say 24px write em(12, 24)
  Based on https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/functions/_px-to-em.scss
==============================================================================*/
@function em($pxval, $base: $font-size-base) {
  @if not unitless($pxval) {
    $pxval: strip-units($pxval);
  }
  @if not unitless($base) {
    $base: strip-units($base);
  }
  @return ($pxval / $base) * 1em;
}
```

Comment: Why is your `scss` file renamed to a `js` file? This is not JS code, it's a plain `scss` code. It's event written at the top of the provided code `SASS HELPERS`. It should be this: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0154/8523/t/8/assets/theme.scss?4793735076848149636

Comment: That's what I'd like to know! I didn't develop this theme. I took it over, so I'm just as surprised as you are.

In my Shopify theme's assets folder, there's both a theme.js.liquid file as well as a theme.scss.liquid file.